How to filter PRs using "AND" and "OR" operator
To filter PRs not involved by John, I use:
-involves-by:john123

To filter PRs not authored by John, I use:
-author:john123


I tried combining the filters like this:
-involves-by:john123 -author:john123 -involves-by:jane123 -author:jane123

But it doesn’t work as expected, its working all like an OR statement.
I was expecting something like:
(-involves-by:john123 AND -author:john123) OR (-involves-by:jane123 AND -author:jane123)

I think my syntax is correct based on the documentation, but it’s not returning any results.

Please defined what "it doesn’t work" means in terms of what you get vs what you expected. Also please describe what query you're filter to construct; you haven't mentioned jane123 in your description but she's in the filter. eg, is it that you what PRs that involve neither john nor jane? Some example data would really help.

@Bohemian Please defined what "it doesn’t work" means response: its already in the description. I updated and bold the text for you. you haven't mentioned jane123 in your description but she's in the filter response: that part is to help set the context for readers. The key point is about combining filters, which I did mention in the description. Anyways i removed that text that is confusing.

It’s just involves, not involves-by. Which query doesn’t return any results? What’s an example of a result you expect to be included? It’s not clear which behavior you’re looking for. Also, author implies involves, so the corrected version of the “I tried combining the filters like this” query is equivalent to just -involves:john123 -involves:jane123.

@Ry- still No results matched your search. It’s not clear which behavior you’re looking for answer: i want to get all PRs that are not reviewed by John and Jane. -involves:john123 -involves:jane123 answer: this should be the answer, the problem with this is it will function as OR operator.
